# SpeechSynthesis API on iOS 17 failed with certain text

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, cjk, speech-synthesis

```js
let voice = null;
function updateVoice() {
  voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().find(voice => voice.lang == 'zh-CN')
  document.getElementById('voice_name').textContent = voice?.name ?? '(No Voice)';
}
speechSynthesis.addEventListener('voiceschanged', updateVoice);
updateVoice()
const speak = document.getElementById('speak');
const text = document.getElementById('text');
speak.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const ssu = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text.value);
  ssu.voice = voice;
  ssu.lang = 'zh-CN';
  ssu.addEventListener('start', e => console.log('start', e));
  ssu.addEventListener('end', e => console.log('end', e));
  ssu.addEventListener('error', e => console.log('error', e));
  speechSynthesis.speak(ssu);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="text">“你好”</textarea>
<div id="voice_name"></div>
<button type="button" id="speak">
Speak
</button>
```

My PWA using Speech Synthesis API simpliy works on Safari iOS 16.5 but it just failed after I upgraded my device to iOS 17. Codes are shown above. When running on my iPhone SE2 with iOS 17, trying to speak `“你好”` (`你好` with CJK quotes `“”`) results nothing happened. However, if you remove the quotes and leave only `你好` in the textarea, and click the Speak button again, it would work as expected. I'm not sure what I can do to get ride of this problem. So could anyone help me find a work around here?

Answer (score 0):

As the text to speak is given by user which is out of my control. I cannot avoid the quote in the text. After some try and error. The best workaround I got so far is:

- Append `“”。` on each text for ssu

It could be tricky but however works.

```js
const extraSuffix = '“”。';

let voice = null;
function updateVoice() {
  voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().find(voice => voice.lang == 'zh-CN')
  document.getElementById('voice_name').textContent = voice?.name ?? '(No Voice)';
}
speechSynthesis.addEventListener('voiceschanged', updateVoice);
updateVoice()
const speak = document.getElementById('speak');
const text = document.getElementById('text');
speak.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const ssu = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text.value + extraSuffix);
  ssu.voice = voice;
  ssu.lang = 'zh-CN';
  ssu.addEventListener('start', e => console.log('start', e));
  ssu.addEventListener('end', e => console.log('end', e));
  ssu.addEventListener('error', e => console.log('error', e));
  speechSynthesis.speak(ssu);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="text">“你好”</textarea>
<div id="voice_name"></div>
<button type="button" id="speak">
Speak
</button>
```

I find out that if I append a `。` at the end of text, the speech synthesis works again. However, `怎么？` and `怎么？。` would have different tune, which is not what I want. But `怎么？“”。` works fine. That's why it use such strange suffix.